# php видит только одно значение из полученного массива файлов

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

здравствуйте, есть `AJAX` запрос

```
function askquestion() {
if (inask) return false;

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('image', $('.uploadimg:eq(0) input').prop('files')[0]);
    data.append('image', $('.uploadimg:eq(1) input').prop('files')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'здесь мой сайт',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            //
        }
    });

}
```

вот php код:

`print_r($_FILES);`

и как видно на изображении, ajax запрос успешно передал 2 изображения, но php видит только 1, с чем связанна данная проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте так: `data.append('image[]'`

Comment: спасибо, помогло)

Comment: спалил второй акк))

Comment: так блин тут репутация просела, не могу вопросы задавать))

Answer (score 1):

Вы так добавляете параметры в `ajax`, И тем самым перезаписывается первый параметр.
Вот ваш код:

```
data.append('image', $('.uploadimg:eq(0) input').prop('files')[0]);
data.append('image', $('.uploadimg:eq(1) input').prop('files')[0]);
```

А надо так:

```
data.append('image1', $('.uploadimg:eq(0) input').prop('files')[0]);
data.append('image2', $('.uploadimg:eq(1) input').prop('files')[0]);
```